# Using extern on Halide with GPU

Tags: c++, image-processing, halide

I try to use extern function in Halide. In my context, I want to do it on GPU.

I compile in AOT compilation with opencl statement.
Of course, opencl can still use CPU, so I use this:

```
halide_set_ocl_device_type("gpu");
```

For now, everything is schedule at compute_root().

First question, if I use compute_root() and OpenCL gpu, did my process will be compute on the device with some CopyHtoD and DtoH? (Or it will be on Host buffer)

Second question, more related to the extern functions. We use some extern call because some of our algorithm is not in Halide. 
Extern call:

```
foo.define_extern("cool_foo", args, Float(32), 4);
```

Extern retrieve:
extern "C" int cool_foo(buffer_t * in, int w, int h, int z, buffer_t * out){ .. }

But, in the cool_foo function, my buffer_t are load only in host memory. The dev address is 0 (default).

If I try to copy the memory before the algorithm:

```
halide_copy_to_dev(NULL, &in);
```

It does nothing.

If I make available only the device memory:

```
in.host = NULL;
```

My host pointer are null, but the device address is still 0.

(dev_dirty is true on my case and host_dirty is false)

Any idea?

EDIT (To answer dsharlet)

Here's the structure of my code:

Parse data correctly on CPU. --> Sent the buffer on the GPU (Using halide_copy_to_dev...) --> Enter in Halide structure, read parameter and Add a boundary condition --> Go in my extern function -->...

I don't have a valid buffer_t in my extern function.
I schedule everything in compute_root(), but use HL_TARGET=host-opencl and set ocl to gpu. 
Before entering in Halide, I can read my device address and it's ok.

Here's my code:

Before Halide, everything was CPU stuff(The pointer) and we transfert it to GPU

```
buffer_t k = { 0, (uint8_t *) k_full, {w_k, h_k, num_patch_x * num_patch_y * 3}, {1, w_k, w_k * h_k}, {0}, sizeof(float), };
#if defined( USEGPU )
    // Transfer into GPU
    halide_copy_to_dev(NULL, &k);
    k.host_dirty = false;
    k.dev_dirty = true;
    //k.host = NULL; // It's k_full
#endif
halide_func(&k)
```

Inside Halide:

```
ImageParam ...
Func process;
process = halide_sub_func(k, width, height, k.channels());
process.compute_root();

...

Func halide_sub_func(ImageParam k, Expr width, Expr height, Expr patches)
{
    Func kBounded("kBounded"), kShifted("kShifted"), khat("khat"), khat_tuple("khat_tuple");
    kBounded = repeat_image(constant_exterior(k, 0.0f), 0, width, 0, height, 0, patches);
    kShifted(x, y, pi) = kBounded(x + k.width() / 2, y + k.height() / 2, pi);

    khat = extern_func(kShifted, width, height, patches);
    khat_tuple(x, y, pi) = Tuple(khat(0, x, y, pi), khat(1, x, y, pi));

    kShifted.compute_root();
    khat.compute_root();

    return khat_tuple;
}
```

Outside Halide(Extern function):

```
inline .... 
{
   //The buffer_t.dev and .host are 0 and null. I expect a null from the host, but the dev..
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that defines and schedules the stage before the extern stage? Is it scheduled on the GPU? If not, I think the behavior you are seeing is expected.

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution for my problem.

I post the answer in code just here. (Since I did a little offline test, the variable name doesn't match)

Inside Halide: (Halide_func.cpp)

```
#include <Halide.h>


 using namespace Halide;

 using namespace Halide::BoundaryConditions;

 Func thirdPartyFunction(ImageParam f);
 Func fourthPartyFunction(ImageParam f);
 Var x, y;

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Input:
    ImageParam f( Float( 32 ), 2, "f" );

    printf(" Argument: %d\n",argc);

    int test = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (test == 1) {
        Func f1;
        f1(x, y) = f(x, y) + 1.0f;
        f1.gpu_tile(x, 256);
        std::vector<Argument> args( 1 );
        args[ 0 ] = f;
        f1.compile_to_file("halide_func", args);

    } else if (test == 2) {
        Func fOutput("fOutput");
        Func fBounded("fBounded");
        fBounded = repeat_image(f, 0, f.width(), 0, f.height());
        fOutput(x, y) = fBounded(x-1, y) + 1.0f;


        fOutput.gpu_tile(x, 256);
        std::vector<Argument> args( 1 );
        args[ 0 ] = f;
        fOutput.compile_to_file("halide_func", args);

    } else if (test == 3) {
        Func h("hOut");

        h = thirdPartyFunction(f);

        h.gpu_tile(x, 256);
        std::vector<Argument> args( 1 );
        args[ 0 ] = f;
        h.compile_to_file("halide_func", args);

    } else {
        Func h("hOut");

        h = fourthPartyFunction(f);

        std::vector<Argument> args( 1 );
        args[ 0 ] = f;
        h.compile_to_file("halide_func", args);
    }
 }

 Func thirdPartyFunction(ImageParam f) {
     Func g("g");
     Func fBounded("fBounded");
     Func h("h");
     //Boundary
     fBounded = repeat_image(f, 0, f.width(), 0, f.height());
     g(x, y) = fBounded(x-1, y) + 1.0f;
     h(x, y) = g(x, y) - 1.0f;

     // Need to be comment out if you want to use GPU schedule.
     //g.compute_root(); //At least one stage schedule alone
     //h.compute_root();

     return h;
 }

Func fourthPartyFunction(ImageParam f) {
    Func fBounded("fBounded");
    Func g("g");
    Func h("h");

    //Boundary
    fBounded = repeat_image(f, 0, f.width(), 0, f.height());

    // Preprocess
    g(x, y) = fBounded(x-1, y) + 1.0f;

    g.compute_root();
    g.gpu_tile(x, y, 256, 1);


    // Extern
    std::vector < ExternFuncArgument > args = { g, f.width(), f.height() };
    h.define_extern("extern_func", args, Int(16), 3);

    h.compute_root();
    return h;
}
```

The external function: (external_func.h)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


#include <clFFT.h> // All OpenCL I need are include.

using namespace std;
// Useful stuff.
void completeDetails2D(buffer_t buffer) {
    // Read all elements:
    std::cout << "Buffer information:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Extent: " << buffer.extent[0] << ", " << buffer.extent[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stride: " << buffer.stride[0] << ", " << buffer.stride[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Min: " << buffer.min[0] << ", " << buffer.min[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elem size: " << buffer.elem_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Host dirty: " << buffer.host_dirty << ", Dev dirty: " << buffer.dev_dirty << std::endl;
    printf("Host pointer: %p, Dev pointer: %" PRIu64 "\n\n\n", buffer.host, buffer.dev);
}

extern cl_context _ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal11weak_cl_ctxE;
extern cl_command_queue _ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal9weak_cl_qE;


extern "C" int extern_func(buffer_t * in, int width, int height, buffer_t * out)
{
    printf("In extern\n");
    completeDetails2D(*in);
    printf("Out extern\n");
    completeDetails2D(*out);

    if(in->dev == 0) {
        // Boundary stuff
        in->min[0] = 0;
        in->min[1] = 0;
        in->extent[0] = width;
        in->extent[1] = height;
        return 0;
    }

    // Super awesome stuff on GPU
    // ...

    cl_context & ctx = _ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal11weak_cl_ctxE; // Found by zougloub
    cl_command_queue & queue = _ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal9weak_cl_qE; // Same

    printf("ctx: %p\n", ctx);

    printf("queue: %p\n", queue);

    cl_mem buffer_in;
    buffer_in = (cl_mem) in->dev;
    cl_mem buffer_out;
    buffer_out = (cl_mem) out->dev;

    // Just copying data from one buffer to another
    int err = clEnqueueCopyBuffer(queue, buffer_in, buffer_out, 0, 0, 256*256*4, 0, NULL, NULL);

    printf("copy: %d\n", err);

    err = clFinish(queue);

    printf("finish: %d\n\n", err);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, the non-Halide stuff: (Halide_test.cpp)

```
#include <halide_func.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>

#include <external_func.h>

// Extern function available inside the .o generated.
#include "HalideRuntime.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Init the kernel in GPU
    halide_set_ocl_device_type("gpu");

    // Create a buffer
    int width = 256;
    int height = 256;
    float * bufferHostIn = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * width * height);
    float * bufferHostOut = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * width * height);

    for( int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        for( int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
            bufferHostIn[i + j * width] = i+j;
        }
    }

    buffer_t bufferHalideIn = {0, (uint8_t *) bufferHostIn, {width, height}, {1, width, width * height}, {0, 0}, sizeof(float), true, false};
    buffer_t bufferHalideOut = {0, (uint8_t *) bufferHostOut, {width, height}, {1, width, width * height}, {0, 0}, sizeof(float), true, false};

    printf("IN\n");
    completeDetails2D(bufferHalideIn);
    printf("Data (host): ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
        printf(" %f, ", bufferHostIn[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("OUT\n");
    completeDetails2D(bufferHalideOut);

    // Send to GPU
    halide_copy_to_dev(NULL, &bufferHalideIn);
    halide_copy_to_dev(NULL, &bufferHalideOut);
    bufferHalideIn.host_dirty = false;
    bufferHalideIn.dev_dirty = true;
    bufferHalideOut.host_dirty = false;
    bufferHalideOut.dev_dirty = true;
    // TRICKS Halide to force the use of device.
    bufferHalideIn.host = NULL;
    bufferHalideOut.host = NULL;

    printf("IN After device\n");
    completeDetails2D(bufferHalideIn);

    // Halide function
    halide_func(&bufferHalideIn, &bufferHalideOut);

    // Get back to HOST
    bufferHalideIn.host = (uint8_t*)bufferHostIn;
    bufferHalideOut.host = (uint8_t*)bufferHostOut;
    halide_copy_to_host(NULL, &bufferHalideOut);
    halide_copy_to_host(NULL, &bufferHalideIn);

    // Validation
    printf("\nOUT\n");
    completeDetails2D(bufferHalideOut);
    printf("Data (host): ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
        printf(" %f, ", bufferHostOut[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Free all
    free(bufferHostIn);
    free(bufferHostOut);

}
```

You can compile the halide_func with the test 4 to use all the Extern functionnality.

Here's some of the conclusion I have. (Thanks to Zalman and zougloub)

- Compute_root don't call the device if you use it alone.
- We need gpu() of gpu_tile() in the code to call GPU routine. (BTW, you need to put all your variable inside)
- gpu_tile les than your item will crash your stuff.
- BoundaryCondition works well in GPU.
- Before calling extern function, the Func that goes as a input need to be:
  f.compute_root(); f.gpu_tile(x,y,...,...); The compute_root in the middle stage is not implicit.
- If the dev address is 0, it's normal, we resend the dimension and the extern will be called again.
- Last stage as a compute_root() implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the bounds inference protocol for external array functions? This takes place when the host pointer of any buffer is NULL. (Briefly, in this case, you need to fill in the extent fields of the buffer_t structures that have NULL host pointers and do nothing else.) If you have already taken care of that, then ignore the above.

If you've tested that the host pointers are non-NULL for all buffers, then calling halide_copy_to_dev should work. You may need to explicitly set host_dirty to true beforehand to get the copy part to happen, depending where the buffer came from. (I would hope Halide gets this right and it is already set if the buffer came from a previous pipeline stage on the CPU. But if the buffer came from something outside Halide, the dirty bits are probably false from initialization. It seems halide_dev_malloc should set dev_dirty if it allocates device memory, and currently it does not.)

I would expect the dev field to be populated after a call to halide_copy_to_dev as the first thing it does is call halide_dev_malloc. You can try calling halide_dev_malloc explicitly yourself, setting host_dirty and then calling halide_copy_to_dev.

Is the previous stage on the host or on the GPU? If it is on the GPU, I'd expect the input buffer to be on the GPU as well.

This API needs work. I am in the middle of a first refactoring of somethings that will help, but ultimately it will require changing the buffer_t structure. It is possible to get most things to work, but it requires a modifying the host_dirty and dev_dirty bits as well as calling the halide_dev* APIs in just the right way. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks Zalman. If my buffer are NULL, I fill the extents fields and quit the extern. But, if I want the host to be NULL and the Dev to have something, what I need to do?  The previous stage of my pipeline(before halide) is on CPU, but I want to use my portion in Halide only on GPU. Last thing, if I schedule in compute_root and use the HL_TARGET=host-opencl and select the gpu, did the code will run on GPU (without optimization) or CPU?